# Jprofiler unable to see Jboss JVM on remote machine

Tags: java, windows, jvm, jboss5.x, jprofiler

I am attempting to hook up JProfiler GUI on my local machine(Windows x64) to a JProfiler agent running on a remote (Windows x64). The remote machine has 2 JVMs - one a JBOSS JVM and another as a Java Application as a Windows Service via wrapper services of YAJSW. These JVMs are started Windows User Profile 1.
I pasted the JProfiler agent zip file on the remote machine and logged into it via mstsc. When I run the jpenable command in cmd (As admin) and it asks me to search for "already running JVMs" - I press 'y' but the cmd window automatically closes out. When I force jpenable to run with the PID of either of those JVMs - it complains that the JVMs cannot be seen by this user. Even using User Profile 1, JProfiler could not see the JBOSS JVM or the other JVM (with Show Services option) with the error message - 'No unprofiled JVMs found'.

My question is - if we have got JVMs on a remote machine started by 1 user, and I attempt to run the JProfiler agent (through jpenable) with user 2 , how can I have the agent see both JVMs to start up profiling so that I can hook up my local JProfiler GUI to either of these JVMs.

Much Appreciated !

Comment: I see jboss5.x so on which JDK version it runs, if it's a 1.5 I think you have to add some option to the jvm on starting in jboss run.bat/sh file.

Comment: And maybe Jprofiler has to run with the same user than jvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the JProfiler attach helper service in the service manager and change its user account to the same user account that is used to start JProfiler. Then JProfiler should be able to show the process in jpenable if you tell it to search for services.

---

**Update for JProfiler 10.0+:**

Since JProfiler 10.0, it is possible to attach to services that are not started by the LocalSystem account. JProfiler can now attach to all services, started by admin and non-admin users.